# Binding a DataContext inside ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to set a DataContext of a UserControl (Panel.xaml/PanelViewModel.cs) through a ListView of another control (PanelList.xaml/PanelListViewModel.cs).

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class PanelListViewModel
    {
        public List<PanelViewModel> Apps { get; set; } = new List<PanelViewModel>
        {
            new PanelViewModel
            {
                ApplicationName = "App 1",
                ApplicationVersion = "v. 1.0.3",
                IsInstalled = true
            },
            new PanelViewModel
            {
                ApplicationName = "App 2",
                ApplicationVersion = "v. 1.0.3",
                IsInstalled = false
            }
        };
    }
```

And have the following UserControl:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:PanelListViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Apps}">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                    <local:Panel DataContext="{Binding}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

It works at first in the designer preview window in VS, but as soon as I build it, the DataContext Binding doesn't work anymore. Please help :)

Comment: You should generally never explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl. Assuming you did that for your Panel control (similar to how you it for PanelList), `DataContext="{Binding}` will not do what you expect. Besides that, the expression `DataContext="{Binding}"`is always redundant.

Comment: @Clemens what you said did the trick. I wasn't aware that they conflict between them. I'm new at this, how can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: This is a common problem, because there are so many "tutorials" on the internet that propagate this programming error. I have marked the question as duplicate.

Comment: Also note that there is no reason to use ListView, unless you set its View property. Otherwise use the simpler base class ListBox.

Answer (score -1):

Can you set a "x:Name" for the ListView and try the following code in the load event, maybe that helps:

C# Code:

```
myListView.DataContext = Apps;
```

XAML Code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Apps}" x:Name="MyListView">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't work as well. The ListView DataContext is correctly set, but the ListView item is a custom UserControl and here is where I want to set the DataContext

Comment: `myListView.DataContext = Apps;` in conjunction with `ItemsSource="{Binding Apps}"` makes no sense.